# how to link pages in different sub folders using include or require

Tags: php, html

I am creating a website and I am splitting my code up into different sections eg header ,body, footer etc. my folder structure is as follows. 
I am trying to link my registration.js to my registration.php how would I achieve this.
I have tried:

include '../../includes/registration.php';

```
webapp (rootfolder)
assests (subfolder)
       css (subfolder)
       js (subfolder)
           registration.js
config (subfolder)
includes (subfolder)
          registration.php
```

Comment: By doing some research and reading up on (creating and) working with (MVC) frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

*I am trying to link my registration.js to my registration.php how would I achieve this.*

If by that you mean to include/call/link the `registration.js` inside `registration.php` file, consider the hierarchy you've provided:

In your `registration.php`:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assests/js/registration.js"></script>
</head>
```

> Note: You might want to spellcheck `assests`.

Comment: i am making a jquery post call in my registration.js to my registration.php file

Answer (score 0):

If this is your hierarchy:

```
webapp/
  |-assests/
  |    |- css/
  |    |- js/
  |       |- registration.js
  |-config/
  |-includes/
      |- registration.php
```

I recommend you change it

'includes' are just that, files you include, you don't want to surfing to your includes folder.  You don't want someone to be able to surf to your database config file even if you've stashed it in a function or class.

Typically you will want:

```
/var/www/
   |- webapp/
   |     |-assets/
   |     |    |-css/
   |     |    |-js/
   |     |    |-images/
   |     |-index.php
   |     |-registration.php
   |     |-ajax.php 
   |-includes/
   |    |-config/
   |    |   |-db_cfg.php
   |    |-functions.php
```

with the webapp php files you can use "include /var/www/includes/..." or include ../includes/..."

Then your html script,css, and image links are "assets/css", "assets/js" and "assets/images"

see also: php routing framework / clean urls